# Change UISlider controller when Table row clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uislider

I want to create a UISlider that when a user selects a tableview row. It updates the min & max value moves the slider to a value set by a variable.

The slider is in a different Viewcontroller then the tableview. I am passing the values to the slider using a struct (Posted below). At this point, I can get the slider to work when I set the struct values in the view controller viewDidLoad. But I am not able to change the UIslider when a tableview row is selected. I think the problem is that the view with the UIslider is not refreshing when the row is selected.  the Tableview is embedded in the view with the slider using a container view.

```
     struct GlobalSliderValues {

        static var minimumValue = Int()
        static var maximumValue = Int()
        static var lowerValue = Int()
        static var UpperValue = Int()
        static var locationValue = Int()
        static var sliderValue = Int()
        static var setValue = Int()
    }

// Slider ViewController 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sliderOutlet.minimumValue = Float(GlobalSliderValues.minimumValue)
    sliderOutlet.maximumValue = Float(GlobalSliderValues.maximumValue)
    sliderOutlet.isContinuous = true
    sliderOutlet.tintColor = UIColor.green
    sliderOutlet.value = Float(GlobalSliderValues.sliderValue)

}


// Method attempting to change Slider

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 3:
        GlobalSliderValues.minimumValue = 100
        GlobalSliderValues.maximumValue = 10000000
        GlobalSliderValues.sliderValue = 100000000

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to refactor the slider assignment also adding `NotificationCenter` to be able to refresh the slider from anywhere, doing so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  sliderOutlet.isContinuous = true
  sliderOutlet.tintColor = UIColor.green
  self.refreshSlider()
}

@objc func refreshSlider() {
  sliderOutlet.minimumValue = Float(GlobalSliderValues.minimumValue)
  sliderOutlet.maximumValue = Float(GlobalSliderValues.maximumValue)
  sliderOutlet.value = Float(GlobalSliderValues.sliderValue)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.refreshSlider), name: Notification.Name("refreshSlider"), object: nil)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
  NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name("refreshSlider"), object: nil)
}
```

and finally inside your `didSelectRowAt` you will have:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  switch indexPath.row {
  case 3:
    GlobalSliderValues.minimumValue = 100
    GlobalSliderValues.maximumValue = 10000000
    GlobalSliderValues.sliderValue = 100000000
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name:Notification.Name("refreshSlider"), object: nil)
  break:
  default:
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the post. I am not sure where to put the refreshSlider() function. The slider and the tableView are not connected to the same viewController. I added the function to the view controller with the slider, no errors. But I am not able to call in "didSelectRowAt" as it's in a different viewController. The tableView is embedded in a container on the slider view controller.